# Warning on render : Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `className`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jsx

GEtting the following error for the div.container and span.text:

Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `className`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: className="true" or className={value.toString()}.

```
  return (
    Array.isArray(contactDetails) &&
    contactDetails.map((item, index) => {
      return item.type === DIVIDER ? (
        <div key={index}>
          <Divider variant={"middle"} className={classes.divider} />
          <div className={classes.dividerText}>{item.text}</div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        item.text && (
          <div className={classes.container} key={index}>
            <div className={classes.icon}>{item.icon}</div>
            <span className={classes.text}>{item.text}</span>
          </div>
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your `classes`-props is a `boolean`. You cannot push a `boolean` (true/false) to `className`.

You could `console.log(classes)`, then you will see, which prop causes the warning.

Comment: How do i navigate to the props once i can see the console log?

Comment: You have to open your browser's dev-tools. Which browser do you use?

Answer (score 1):

It means at least one of the className values is boolean instead of string. we can not say anything more with this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when i didn't give a value to className attribute like below, probably one of your variable is null or boolean etc.

```
<img className src={...} .../>
```